# VS2008 keeps hanging busy when clicking design view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

VS2008 express web developer keeps hanging whenever I try to go to design mode. this just started a couple days ago for some reason, was fine before.

whenever i click design mode, the whole thing freezes, any clicks anywhere on the program give me a 'ding' sound until i end task in task manager.

usually there's no error to see, though sometimes i'll see some error in the status update about jquery intellisense problems loading, the thing is that this happens even on a brand new project and default.aspx with no jquery attached.

any ideas? this is very frustrating, i can no longer work.

multiple uninstalls and fresh installs have done nothing to help.

Answer (score 3):

VS gets hang many times when we click on its design page (aspx) and it dies.
This issue can be solved by following these steps – 
1.  Go to control Panel
2.  Add or Remove programs
3.  Find Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component.
4.  Click on change and then click Repair.
5.  Restart your system and hopefully your problem will get solved. 

Answer (score 2):

It might be the ToolBox refreshing itself.  Try this tip:

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/07/23/speed-up-the-visual-studio-toolbox.aspx

Comment: i don't think that option is available in web developer express edition, i forgot to mention i'm using the free express edition sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is a good resolution on MSDN blog. Follow the link below:

[Troubleshooting "Visual Studio 2008 Design view hangs" issues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2008/10/03/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2008-design-view-hangs-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

This link fixed my hang problem:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2009/07/23/visual-studio-2008-hangs-on-switching-to-design-view/

`Run regedit.exe and look for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\ProductVersion key. If key is missing, add it and set “LastProduct” value to 12.0.4518.1066. Restart the machine after this step.`

Also, you can try repair "Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component" in programs and features.